# I am unable to get the correct worksheet name when looping through a workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to collect data from multiple workbooks by checking the worksheet names.
However when i run my code to check the worksheetname(which is Raw Data), i am getting a false result. The code is returning only Sheet1 and Sheet2.
Below is the code:

```
Function WorksheetRAWExists(wsName As String) As Boolean

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ret As Boolean

ret = False
wsName = UCase(wsName)
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If UCase(ws.Name) = "RAW DATA" Then
        ret = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next
WorksheetRAWExists = ret

End Function
```

Comment: Your code is only looking at the workbook containing the code - was that your intention?

Comment: where is your reference to workbook in the function?

Comment: Is there an extra space in the middle or at the end of the worksheet name?  That's tripped me up before.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you loop through "ThisWorkbook" in your for-each, which always checks the worksheet collection in the workbook you're running the VBA code from.

If you're looking to loop through all sheets in all open workbooks then you could do something like so:

```
Sub test()
Dim wbk As Workbook, ws As Worksheet

For Each wbk In Workbooks
    For Each ws In wbk.Worksheets
        MsgBox ws.Name
    Next ws
Next wbk

End Sub
```

Edit:

You could also pass the workbook name or index (or the workbook reference itself) to your function and check that specific reference in the workbook collection, in case looping through all open workbooks isn't what you want.